# How long should a route be in an application? My route is getting longer

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am building a large scale application. and I was wondering how long a route should be? or what is recommended? My longest route is:

```
 http://localhost:3000/#/mc/accessories/watches/wa/mens watches
```

This is my app.ts route:

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/mc', component: MainCategoryComponent }
])
```

This is my shopping.ts route:

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/cl', component: ClothesComponent },
  { path: '/ac', component: AccessoriesComponent },
  { path: '/ph', component: PharmacyComponent },
  { path: '/sh', component: ShoesComponent },
  { path: '/to', component: ToysComponent },
  { path: '/en', component: EntertainmentComponent },
  { path: '/vi', component: VideoGamesComponent },
  { path: '/el', component: ElectronicsComponent }  
])
```

This is my accessory-route.ts

```
@Routes([   
  { path: '/wa', component: WatchComponent },
```

])

This is my watch.ts route:

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/:id', component: WatchDetailComponent },    
  { path: '/h', component: WatchHomeComponent },
  { path: '/', component: WatchHomeComponent }
])
```

When I search for mens watches, my route takes me to

```
http://localhost:3000/#/mc/accessories/watches/wa/mens watches
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter you have how many routes. Angular is intelligent enough to carry out correct path. But for you managing the route in modular approach would help in easy management. But careful in forbidden the route.